# How to show hidden content according to clicked value jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**sorry for the midunderstanding. I meant index, not value. Sorry.**

I am wondering if there is a way to use the value of the shown content ".wbox" of this jsfiddle example to coincide with the hidden value, that when clicked will show the hidden content?

For example, When Cont 1 is clicked, hidden box 1 shows. When Cont2 is clicked, hidden box 2 shows... and so forth.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kqbLtn8b/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="content one">
        <h1>Cont 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content two">
        <h1>Cont 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content three">
        <h1>Cont 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden-content">
    <div class="hidden-box b-one">one</div>
    <div class="hidden-box b-two">two</div>
    <div class="hidden-box b-three">three</div>    
</div>
```

jquery:

```
var boxVal = $('.box').val();
```

Thanks for any help!

What I am really trying to do is shorten the code from something like this:

```
$('.one').on('click', function(){
    $('.b-one').show()
});
```

and so forth with the rest

Comment: The only code I see is a variable receiving the value of some selected element. And this won't work, because `.val()` won't return a value here. `.box` will select a `div`, which doesn't have a value. It may have `.html()` or `.text()`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I added some more, I am just trying to shorten the code from having to write out what I just added three times. Is there a way to shorten it?

Comment: @Chipe take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqbLtn8b/8/). I moved `.content` `div`s second classes to `data-value` and `display:none;` from `.hidden-content` to `.hidden-box`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : use index of `content` div to show `hidden-box`

```
$(function(){
    $('.content').click(function(){
      var index = $(this).index();
        $('.hidden-content .hidden-box:eq('+index+')').show();
    });
});
```

And make change in your css, instead of hiding `hidden-content` div you need to hide `hidden-box`. So change your

```
.hidden-content{
    display:none;
}
```

to

```
.hidden-box{
    display:none;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kqbLtn8b/7/)**

Comment: Just to mention: using `:eq` instead of additional classes (or `data-`) is indeed simplier, but there is danger that someone in future will rotate two elements only in one part and therefore will ruin all.

Comment: .index... duh, that is what I meant. Man do I feel dumb. Thanks!

Comment: @Regent, yeah I agree that my solution is totally depends on the html structure and it may not work if there will be any change in element position.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way (although not so reliable, as it would break if you change your classes):

```js
$(function () {
    $('.content').on('click', function () {
        var className = $(this).attr('class').replace('content', '').trim();        
        $('.hidden-box').hide();
        $('.b-' + className).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden-box {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <div class="content one">
        <h1>Cont 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content two">
        <h1>Cont 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content three">
        <h1>Cont 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden-content">
    <div class="hidden-box b-one">one</div>
    <div class="hidden-box b-two">two</div>
    <div class="hidden-box b-three">three</div>    
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on @Regent comment which I agree to, this would be a more reliable way because it will work even if you change your markup.
You just need to add a `data` attribute to your markup that will be used to match elements:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.content').on('click', function () {        
        var sel = $(this).data('rel');
        
        $('.hidden-box').each(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).data('rel') == sel);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden-box {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <div class="content one" data-rel="1">
        <h1>Cont 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content two" data-rel="2">
        <h1>Cont 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content three" data-rel="3">
        <h1>Cont 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden-content">
    <div class="hidden-box b-one" data-rel="1">one</div>
    <div class="hidden-box b-two" data-rel="2">two</div>
    <div class="hidden-box b-three" data-rel="3">three</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that's why I have suggested to use `data-`. It will simplify and make more reliable the process of choosing related element (without `replace`, `trim`).

Comment: @Regent I agree. This would be the only reliable way, and it would also separate concerns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the current HTML you have, it is going to be cumbersome and dirty since there are 2 ways to handle that scenario.

1. Translate a string like "Cont 1" into "one", "Cont 2" into "two". It's all well and good till nine but what about 100 -> hundred? Or even thousand?
2. The other approach is instead of  naming your hidden boxes as "b-one", "b-two", you can name them "b-1", "b-2", "b-3". That way you can just detect the clicked element and then wipe of the "Cont " part and then use the remainder of the string to get the hidden part's class.

Both the above cases will still give you a very very dirty code since you have to get the `.html()` of the clicked element and stip of `h1` tags.

So my suggestion would be to follow the below method.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="content one" rel="1">
        <h1>Cont 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content two" rel="2">
        <h1>Cont 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content three" rel="3">
        <h1>Cont 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden-content">
    <div class="hidden-box b-1">one</div>
    <div class="hidden-box b-2">two</div>
    <div class="hidden-box b-2">three</div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.content').on('click', function(){
    var divNum = this.rel;

    $('.b-'+divNum).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend restructuring your HTML in the following way:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="content" id= "c1">
    <h1>Cont 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="content" id= "c2">
    <h1>Cont 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="content" id= "c3">
    <h1>Cont 3</h1>
</div>
```

```
<div class="hidden-content">
<div class="hidden-box" id= "h1">one</div>
<div class="hidden-box" id= "h2">two</div>
<div class="hidden-box" id= "h3">three</div>
```

then use this as your jquery code:

```
$('.content').click(function(){
var num = $(this).attr('id').split("c")[1];
$("#h"+num).show();
});
```

and by the way, change your css too:

```
.hidden-content{
/*    display:none;*/
}
.hidden-box{
width:35px;
height:35px;
border:1px solid black;
display:none;
}
```